# Resolving an outer promise from another — alternating execution order?

Tags: javascript, promise

I noticed some interesting behavior when resolving one promise from another:

```js
const someTask = callback => {
  new Promise(res => res())
    .then(() => callback())
    .then(() => console.log("A 1!"))
    .then(() => console.log("A 2!"));
};

new Promise(res => someTask(res))
  .then(() => console.log("B 1!"))
  .then(() => console.log("B 2!"));
```

This outputs:

```
B 1!
A 1!
B 2!
A 2!
```

My thought would be that it would:

1. *At least* enqueue one of the chains all at once so that all the A's `.then` callbacks would run first followed by B's, or vice versa, however they seem to alternate back and forth which is puzzling.
2. Run A's first log statement before B, since it resolved before B.

I understand that this is both potentially implementation-dependent and that I shouldn't rely on execution order here (in my project I just care about A resolving B when it's done), but it intrigues me why this is happening. This is with native promises and Bluebird yields the same output.

Comment: lookup javascript event loop and microtasks - it's complicated

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm familiar with how the event loop works and microtasks—I can't seem to explain this behavior though based on that.

Comment: well ... put a `.then(() => {})` before `.then(() => console.log("B 1!"))` ... no log A 1 is first ... does that give you any insight? if you realise .then returns a (new) Promise then it should be clear why the B1 logs first

Comment: `new Promise(res => someTask(res))` will wait only untill the `res ` is not called then 
 after everything is parallel. so `.then` of both promises will run in parallel , `someTask's` `.then` are delayed because of its `callback`, rather using console.log try to put a delay using `settimeout` then it will be clearer.

Comment: @AZ_ I don’t understand how everything is running in parallel given that JS is single-threaded — somehow they have to be enqueued onto the microtask queue but I’m still unclear of how the ordering happens based on the fact that a new promise is returned for each .then.

Comment: single-threaded but event-driven, all the chained `.then` are in order even in your example, but `new Promise(res => someTask(res))` and `new Promise(res => res())` are not chained to excute in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I am going to avoid spec terminology like EnqoeueJob to not be more confusing</sub>

Whenever you `.then(() => { ... })` that enqueues a microtask. Microtasks always run when there is only platform code remaining so "last" and always run before I/O.

In you case:

- All promise constructors run synchronously - as they always do.
- Your `then`s always run on a new microtick.

This means that in your case:

1. First promise constructor runs synchronously calling someTask.
2. someTask creates a promise and fulfills it synchronously.
3. A microtick passes, the `then` is called which fulfills the original promise.
4. Its then is scheduled and also the then of the original promise
5. Those thens both schedule thens, which alternate

This is because microticks just schedule at the end of a microtask queue. So alternating is the "correct" behavior.

That is not implementation defined - although that was a coincidence and a mistake when building promises. You can but shouldn't rely on that order.

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed explanation. So I’m wondering now: when you say “its then is scheduled and also the then of the original promise”, how does this work exactly? How does the .then of the original promise get scheduled after—is it that the enqueue of the first B .then gets scheduled while callback() is still on the call stack?

Comment: `Promise.resolve().then(callback)` here callback gets scheduled _after every microtick that is also scheduled. Promise.resolve().then(callback).then(callback2)` here callback2 gets scheduled after `callback` as well as anything `callback` scheduled. It is easier to see this in the A+ spec than in the ECMAScript spec: https://promisesaplus.com/#point-34

Comment: thank you! And just one more follow up: you say “microticks just schedule at the end of the microtask queue” => alternating behavior. Would you mind elaborating on why that causes the alternation? I just thought microticks were an iteration of the microtask queue, so I don’t quite see why their scheduling plays a role.

Comment: Every time a promise schedules a then callback it schedules it after all existing callbacks. It is silly but spec mandated which means that scheduling is always consistent (a good thing mostly)

Comment: Awesome—so to clarify that I'm understanding this correctly, the reason why B's `then` gets called before A is because `someTask` resolves synchronously which schedules its callback (and this happens before A's first `.then` finishes), and then B returns and A schedules its second `.then` callback? That's why B is first in the microtask queue? So in other words, only the immediate next `.then` statement gets enqueued and only when the current promise has fulfilled. This would make sense to me but I want to clarify I'm not thinking about it the wrong way.

Comment: That is right - yes - and while it is guaranteed by the spec I wouldn't rely on it